# Reverse Geocoder Returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

So, I am using google's reverse geocoder, so what I originally do is enter an address such as, tokyo, then I get that latlng take the latlng and place it back into the geocoder to receive the proper name of the location but instead it just returns undefined. My code is:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var place = document.getElementById("location").value;
var name;
var place_latlng;
geocoder.geocode({'address' : place}, function(results, status){
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
    place_latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
    addMarker(place_latlng);
  }
});
geocoder.geocode({'latLng' : place_latlng},function(results, status){
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
    name = results[0].formatted_address;
  }
});
```

name ends up being undefined every time, is there a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Geocoder is asynchronous, you need to use the data returned by the Geocoder inside its callback function (not tested):

```
geocoder.geocode({'address' : place}, function(results, status){
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
    place_latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
    addMarker(place_latlng);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng' : place_latlng},function(results, status){
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
        name = results[0].formatted_address;
        alert("name = "+name);
      } else { alert("reverse geocode of "+place_latlng+ " failed ("+status+")"); }
    });
  } else { alert("geocode of "+place+" failed ("+status+")"); }
});
```

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_simpleMap_geocodeReverseGeocode.html)

Comment: Ahh, this worked, when i call the alert, it displays the correct address, but when I go to add the name to the table it displays undefined, does this have anything to do with local scope of variables?

Comment: No. You need to use the name variable inside the callback function (where the alert is).

Comment: Added an example.  You may find that you need process all the results to find the best one (try using "Delaware").

Comment: Yea, I was gonna say how can I determine which is the best result?

Comment: Look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding), it states: "Addresses are returned in the order of best to least matches. Generally, the more exact address is the most prominent result, as it is in this case. Note that we return different types of addresses, from the most specific street address to less specific political entities such as neighborhoods, cities, counties, states, etc. If you wish to match a more general address, you may wish to inspect the results[].types field."

Comment: I read that, the only thing is sometimes when you search more remote places, there isn't always for example a seventh result, or the first result might be extremely long but the second or third is perfect. Just curious if there is a way to filter them

Comment: Look for one or more "types" that meet your requirements (whatever they are).